# Downloading the “The LATEX Com­pan­ion”, sec­ond edi­tion example files from CTAN

Tags: examples, ctan

I learned that many of (La)TeX book examples are stored in `http://ctan.org/tex-archive/info/examples` directory.

[image]

However, the directory with examples from the book LaTeX Companion 2nd ed does not provide the feature to download files in one zip file.

[image]

In this case, how to download all the files in the CTAN example directory?

Googling to find this site (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23446635/how-to-download-http-directory-with-all-files-and-sub-directories-as-they-appear#) to use wget, but with this command, I could not download any file.

`wget -r -np -nH --cut-dirs=3 -R index.html http://ctan.org/tex-archive/info/examples/LaTeX_Companion_2ed/`

How to download example files in a CTAN directory?

Comment: This seems off-topic. The only sense in which it is related to TeX is that you are trying to download files having to do with TeX. But the question would be just the same if you were downloading papers about psychotherapeutic relationships with goldfish. Wouldn't this be best asked elsewhere?

Comment: Efficiently downloading files from CTAN in bulk seems an acceptable question for here to me. There may be CTAN-specific answers which would not appear elsewhere. That said, getting the command the OP has found to work probably is a bit off-topic here and better asked elsewhere.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In a web browser type `ftp://ftp.ctan.org/tex-archive/info/examples/` in the address bar, and log in as a guest. There is a `tlc2.zip` file that zips all the example file. The `LaTeX_Companion_2ed` directory is symbolically linked to `ltc2` directory, and I guess that's the reason why it does not show the zip file to download.

[image]

When you can access with http://ctan.org/tex-archive/info/examples/tlc2, you can see the zip file to download.

[image]

Answer (score 6):

If you write `ftp://tug.org/tex-archive/info/examples/` in the address bar, the same resources are available. You can use any FTP software to download a directory. If you use FTP software (as opposed to accessing the FTP server in a web browser) you need to use the username `anonymous` and an e-mail address (of your choice) as a password.